# How to Find Out Which Record Automapper Errors Out On?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using automapper. The code looks something like this:

```
var processedRecords = await queriedRecords.Project(x =>   
                               Mapper.Map<BsonDocument, RecordViewModel>(x)).ToListAsync();
```

My problem is that I cannot put System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() inside the map definition. Is there any way to know which record automapper errors out on? The way I have been doing it is putting a break point in and clicking continue, but now I am working with a db with millions of records, so obviously that's not practical.

The exception is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Which I assume means that the object doesn't have the property I am trying to map, but it's irrelevant to the q. More interested in the theory here.

Comment: When you get the exception and visual studio opens the debugger, are you able to mouse over `x` and see what it's value is?

Comment: Good thought, but it's an automapper exception and I can't click out of it until I click "Ok" or whatever, at which point it moves on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *can* actually put a `Debug.WriteLine()` in your lambda here. Simply make it a block instead of just an expression:

```
var processedRecords = await queriedRecords.Project(x =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x);
        return Mapper.Map<BsonDocument, RecordViewModel>(x);
    }).ToListAsync();
```

You can also put a `try`/`catch` around the `Mapper.Map<,>()` call if you want to now.

Comment: I am getting the following exception: "Error 1909 A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree", but that probably has to do with all our weird automapper usage and I understand how your answer would apply in a normal scenario. I will try the try/catch. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @VSO Hmm... I've never used automapper before (honestly don't even know what it is), so I don't know how to fix your problem. I hope somebody else can help you with that!

Comment: @VSO for the sake of debugging, you might try changing it to `.Select(x => ...)`  If you're using Linq to sql or Entity Framework, or something like it, you might have to put a `.ToList()` before the `Select(...`

Comment: @JashaszunIt's: All good, you were very helpful. I am sure a lot of people will find your reply useful for troubleshooting lambda (including in entity framework) and such.  In the meantime, if anyone else has any other ideas, that's cool.

Comment: @Sam: I am mapping from MongoDb to an entity view model, I will see what I can do with that. Ty for the suggestions!